# PostgreSQL: cannot see schemas

Tags: postgresql

So I am using PostgreSQL 12 and pgAdmin4. I created two new schema from pgAdmin4, `ml` and `web` in a database `testingDB`. But when I access them from terminal, I could only see `public` schema. How can I view other schemas?

```
$ psql -U awspostgres -h address -p 5432 -d testingDB
```

[image: pgAdmin]

[image: terminal access]

Comment: the user might not have permission for the new schema

Comment: any suggestion to how I can change the permission? I'm using aws rds for postgresql

Comment: not able to interpret your comments. Try with the same user which created the schema and see if it is a permission issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the tables in a schema to be visible with `\dt`, either be explicit:

```
\dt ml.*
```

or add the schema to your `search_path`:

```
SET search_path = ml, web, public;
```

If you want the latter change to be persistent for all connections to the database

```
ALTER DATABASE "testingDB" SET search_path = ml, web, public;
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres can have multiple databases under one DBMS instance. Make sure you are connnecting to a database by specifying the name with the `-d` flag to `psql`:

```
$ psql -U awspostgres -h address -p 5432 -d <db name> testingDB
```

Once connected to postgres (and even if you didn't provide a database name when you started `psql`), you can show databases with `\l` and connect to one using `\c <db name>`

Comment: yes, I did that but it shows the same result... I created random schema -> CREATE SCHEMA testing; but when I type \dt I can only see public schema... But I could see the schema when I access them from pgAdmin

Comment: @Peter what happens if you do `select catalog_name, schema_name, schema_owner from information_schema.schemata` ? also `select datname, datdba, datistemplate, datallowconn, datconnlimit, datact from pg_database` ?

Comment: There are list of schemas and all the tables. With the second line, I received datname=testingDB, datdba=16398, datistemplate = f, datallowconn = t, datconnlimit= -1. Solved my problem with the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the database and look at the Properties. In the Advanced tab of the Properties, remove any Schema restrictions that might have been specified.  Restart the pgAdmin4 client. All the Schemas should be visible now.